# Prevent Timber from escaping `&&` when using with ACF_Blocks

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

Here is my timber block render function

```php
function render_swiper_block($block, $content = '', $is_preview = false)
{
    $context = Timber::context();
    // Store block values.
    $context['block'] = $block;
    // post id
    $context['id'] = get_the_id();
    // Store field values.
    $context['fields'] = get_fields();
    // Store $is_preview value.
    $context['is_preview'] = $is_preview;
    // Render the block.
    Timber::render('admin/swiper.twig', $context);
}
```

The problem occurs when I initiate swiper slider from within script tag inside `swiper.twig` like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty('Swiper')) {
            let swiper = {
                el: '.{{ block.id }}',
                instance: '',
                breakpoint: 1023,
                active: false,
                config: {
                    loop: true,
                    centeredSlides: true,
                    slidesPerView: 'auto',
                    spaceBetween: 1,
                    // Navigation arrows
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.arrow-next',
                        prevEl: '.arrow-prev',
                    },
                },
            }

            swiper.instance = new Swiper(swiper.el, swiper.config)
            if (window.innerWidth > swiper.breakpoint) {
                swiper.active = true
            }

            addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => {
                if (window.innerWidth > swiper.breakpoint && swiper.active === false) {
                    swiper.instance = new Swiper(swiper.el, swiper.config)
                    swiper.active = true
                }
                if (window.innerWidth <= swiper.breakpoint && swiper.active === true) {
                    swiper.instance.destroy(true, true)
                    swiper.active = false
                }
            }, 300))
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
</script>
```

`post.content` escapes `&&` and instead prints `&#038;&#038;`, I know that its WordPress filter apply_filters('the_content', $content) does that. But is there a way around it for my usecase?

Comment: What if you add the `<script>` part of your template to the footer outside of your content using the [`wp_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/). You could even call that from inside your `render_swiper_block()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Have use tried using `{{ var|raw }}`?

> The raw filter marks the value as being “safe”, which means that in an
> environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be
> escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it.

Ref: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html